# Make words pulsate jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGBEyo

I have a difficult task as you saw in the title of the question.

I'm doing a plugin that makes the words move in the screen, increase in size with a sharpen effect, and decrease in size with a blur effect, and the most difficult — one respect other if they have the same name, you may ask: what do you mean?

They have this totally random behavior to grow and stay focus, get smaller and become blurred, however I need make two words with the same name never become clear at same time.

My plugin works like this:

```
<span class="word" data-float="true" data-range-x="100" data-range-y="100" data-top="500" data-left="50" data-size="25">Love</span>

If data-float is true, the word is authorised to use the plugin
data-range-x = the maximum x range that can move
data-range-y = the maximum y range that can move
data-top = the top initial position
data-left = the left initial position
data-size = the size of the word
```

So, is possible to make them respect each other, if they have the same name?

Working plugin it three love words:

```js
+ function($) {

  var Float = function(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.wrapper;
    this.settings = {
      rangeX : element.data('range-x') || 100,
      rangeY : element.data('range-y') || 100,
      speed  : element.data('speed')   || 5000,
      top    : element.data('top')     || 0,
      left   : element.data('left')    || 0,
      size   : element.data('size')    || 20
    };
  };

  Float.prototype.init = function() {
    this.setPosition();
    this.setSize();
    this.setWrapper();
    this.andWalk();

  };

  Float.prototype.setPosition = function() {
    this.element
      .css('top', this.settings.top)
      .css('left', this.settings.left); 
  };
  
  Float.prototype.setSize = function() {
    this.element.css('font-size', this.settings.size + 'px');
    if (this.settings.size <= 20) this.setShadow();      
  };
  
  Float.prototype.setShadow = function() {
    console.log('test');
    this.element.css('color', 'transparent');          
  };

  Float.prototype.setWrapper = function() {
    this.wrapper = $('<div/>').css({
      'width': this.element.outerWidth(true),
      'height': this.element.outerHeight(true),
      'z-index': this.element.css('zIndex')
    });

    this.wrapper.css({
      'position': this.element.css('position'),
      'top': this.element.position().top,
      'left': this.element.position().left,
      'float': this.element.css('position') === 'absolute' ? 'none' : 'left'
    });

    this.element.wrap(this.wrapper).css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'top': 0,
      'left': 0
    });
  };

  Float.prototype.andWalk = function() {
    var self = this;
    var newX = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.settings.rangeX) - this.settings.rangeX / 2;
    var newY = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.settings.rangeY) - this.settings.rangeY / 2 - 0;
    var newS = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.settings.speed)  + this.settings.speed  / 2;
    var newF;
    
    if (this.settings.size > 40) { newF = Math.floor(Math.random() * (70 - 15 + 1) + 15); } 
    else if (this.settings.size <= 25) { newF = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25 - 15 + 1) + 15); } 
    else { newF = Math.floor(Math.random() * (40 - 15 + 1) + 15); }

    this.element.animate({
      'fontSize': newF,
      'color': newF >= 25 ? '#FFFFFF' : 'transparent',
      'top': newY,
      'left': newX
    }, newS, function() {
      self.andWalk();
    });
  };

  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('[data-float]').each(function() {
      var element = $(this).data('float') || false;

      if (element) {
        var float = new Float($(this));
        float.init();
      }
    });
  });
}(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.word {
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<span class="word" data-float="true" data-index="1" data-range-x="100" data-range-y="100" data-top="500" data-left="50" data-size="25">Love</span>
<span class="word" data-float="true" data-index="2" data-range-x="100" data-range-y="100" data-top="90" data-left="290" data-size="40">Love</span>
<span class="word" data-float="true" data-index="3" data-range-x="100" data-range-y="100" data-top="500" data-left="290" data-size="70">Love</span>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: CSS animations would make this *so* much easier / simpler.

Comment: Agree, but i need give support for IE8.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari you can always use CSS3 for all other browsers. Detect the stupid IE8 and make it jaggy. But just for him.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari when you say *"with the same name"* you mean: *elements that have the same text* ?

Comment: Yes, the same text @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: Since your (I suppose it's yours...) code is totally *at-random* , meaning you never know when an effect is going to end (be blurred or totally sharp), at least not now, you should implement a function that, before assigning an animation to an element > will first examine all other elements having the same text > get their end animation times and act respectively. I guess it's too much work for something that is doing it already quite well. I mean I think that after you do what you're trying to do the difference will not be quite visible...

Comment: Also if you take in consideration (for example let's say) that you have 20+ elements saying "Love"... hell, how you plan to achieve what you want? what should be than the exact calculation for *"yey, that's the right timing for you in respect to all other "Love" elements"*...

Comment: So I thought of implementing a data-index and a data-same-as. Then each element would have a different data-index and the data-same-as would an array of index elements that are like him. I do not know ... what do you think of this idea?

Comment: I would also add some smoothing to get rid of the shocking effect. refer to the question and solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438734/jquery-smooth-animation

Answer (score 1):

You may want to leverage the [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library as it uses CSS3 transitions to animate elements with pulse, flip, zoom, rotate, roll, fade and other effects. Then you could use jquery or pure javascript to call these effects.

Here is a jsfiddle I made to demonstrate how you can call the effects from this library with jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/ashk3l/qxfj8L2d/

Essentially your HTML could look something like this:

```
<h1 class="your-element">Hello!</h1>
```

And your jQuery call could look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.your-element').addClass('animated pulse');
});
```